# Disabling text selection popup menu without disabling selection altogether

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, ios

I'm developing a custom e-reader app. I would like to make a custom highlighting menu, but I'm having trouble disabling the "Copy/Paste/Share" menu that pops up when text is selected on mobile devices. As far as I have researched, it seems impossible to disable without disabling selection altogether. But I wonder if by chance anyone has found a workaround.

I am aware of `user-select: none` which disables all selection. This is not desirable for me because I will need to access the javascript selection API for saving highlights, among other things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't listen for `contextmenu` event and cancel it - work for you? It works for me on Android phone.

```js
window.addEventListener("contextmenu", e =>
{
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("selected text:", window.getSelection().toString());
});
```

```html
some text
```

Comment: Thanks! Works for android, but not for iOS unfortunately

Comment: This does not work on Chrome for Windows but it does seem to work on Android.

Comment: this doesn't work on Android Firefox either. I'm not sure about Chrome etc. `e.preventDefault()` prevents the entire default event, including selection. OP said they don't want to disable selection